# fetch value in multidimensional associative array?

Tags: php, associative-array

I have a SESSION array **$_SESSION['cart']**

for example it has value as

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1420
            [item_qty] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1522
            [item_qty] => 1
        )
)
```

Now let's say I have **item_id = 1420**

now I want to increase the **item_qty** for **item_id = 1420**  and also I have to set it in that SESSION array.

What I tried it :

```
  foreach($_SESSION['Cartquantity'] as $key => $d)
    {
         if(isset($d)) {
                   if($d['item_id'] == $_GET['item_id'])
                   {
                        $d['item_quntity'] = $d['item_quantity']+1;
                   }
           }
            else{

               }
   }
```

It's not working ?

Comment: Make sure you have session with name `Cartquantity` or `cart` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating over `$_SESSION['Cartquantity']` but have told us that the array is stored in `$_SESSION['cart']`.

Also, this:

```
$d['tem_quntity'] = $d['item_quantity']+1;
```

Should be:

```
$d['item_qty'] = $d['item_qty']+1;
```

Finally, you'll need to make `$d` a reference by prepending an ampersand (`&`) to it in the `foreach` condition.

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => &$d)
    {
         if($d) {
                   if($d['item_id'] == $_GET['item_id'])
                   {
                        $d['item_qty'] = $d['item_qty']+1;
                   }
           }
            else{

               }
   }
```

Comment: dude but it's not adding in session array

Comment: Are you putting the `&` before the `$d` in the `foreach` condition?

Answer (score 1):

Use reference &$d

```
foreach($_SESSION['Cartquantity'] as $key => &$d)
    {
         if($d) {
                   if($d['item_id'] == $_GET['item_id'])
                   {
                        $d['tem_quntity'] = $d['item_quantity']+1;
                   }
           }
            else{

               }
   }
```

or

```
foreach($_SESSION['Cartquantity'] as $key => $d)
    {
         if($d) {
                   if($d['item_id'] == $_GET['item_id'])
                   {
                        $_SESSION['Cartquantity'][$key]['item_quntity'] = $d['item_quantity']+1;
                   }
           }
            else{

               }
   }
```

Comment: That second example doesn't need that reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for `!empty($array)`

```
if(!empty($d))
```

because it array so you need to check for if its do not have any elements inside of it.

If you want to know if the array is defined , then use `isset($d)`.

If you want to know if a particular key is defined, use `isset($d['item_id'])`.

If you want to know if an array has not empty and has key value pairs , use `!empty($d)`.

Answer (score 0):

use it:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $d)
    {
         if($d) {
                   if($d['item_id'] == $_GET['item_id'])
                   {
                        $d['tem_quntity'] = $d['item_qty']+1;
                   }
           }
            else{

               }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$d['tem_quntity'] = $d['item_quantity']+1;
```

to

```
$d['item_qty'] = $d['item_qty']+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call by

```
foreach ($_SESSION['Cartquantity'] as $value))
{
  if(isset($value))
  {
   if($value['item_id'] == $_GET['item_id'])
     {
      $value['item_quntity'] = $value['item_quantity']+1;
     }
  }
  else
  {

  }

}
```

Comment: how you you will get `$d['item_id']`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val)
{
    foreach($val as $subK)
    {
       if($_GET["item_id"]==$subk["item_id"])
       {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$key]["item_id"]=$_SESSION['cart'][$key]["item_quantity"]+1;
       }
    }
}
```